# How do I control the Hellstorm Missile?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

How do I accelerate the hellstorm missile in multi-player so that it speeds up like the predator missiles in MW2/MW3?  Also, is there a way to control the spread when you break it up or is it just random?

I've tried pressing different buttons to accelerate the missile but I usually end up hitting the wrong button and detonating it or running out of time and having to detonate it so that it's actually useful.  I'm not very good and don't get to this score streak often so I'd like to make the most of it when I do get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Left trigger.

As you can see here on the HUD it tells you the controls - as with all other player-controllable scorestreaks.

[image]
([from the Call of Duty wikia](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Hellstorm_Missile))

Comment: My girlfriend did the screen adjustment and that part is slightly cut off my screen so that would explain why I didn't see it.  Thanks, I feel dumb now.